# ipad2 safari showing poor quality jpg

Tags: html, css, ipad

I'm having some difficulties getting a large jpg to show properly on an ipad 2. The file is 9577x600 pixels and is set as a background image on a div. I've defined `-webkit-background-size` on that div and set it to the same dimensions as the image. I also set my viewport meta tag to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

My css is:

```
#content { position: relative; background: url(../images/infographic.jpg) left top no-repeat; width: 9577px; height: 600px; -webkit-background-size: 9577px 600px; }
```

Here is a screenshot of what I'm getting on the ipad compared to what I'm seeing on my desktop:

[image]

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: can you add the code?? image tag and css related to image

Comment: I'm going to assume the 9577 is a typo and you meant 957? Which version of iPad, unless it's the iPad 1 you're dealing with the retina display, since your image is already smaller than the viewport by a touch you're going to be scaling it up which is a disaster in the best of cases. Search Google for designing for the retina display.

Comment: It isn't a typo - it's a very wide image. I'm just working with the ipad2 for now, retina isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved - I had to split up the large image into two and have them as background images on two different divs. The ipad must have struggled with the large pixel dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the double sized images (HD Image) for devices like phone and ipad.

For example your display image dimension is 200*200 then you should take the original image of 400*400 dimensio and use `max-width` or `width` property to set the original dimension of the image.

Read this [**ARTICLE**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Explained/Explained.html) for more information

Comment: It isn't an image on its own - it's a background image on a div and retina isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without the `meta` tag line you have there and/or without the `-webkit-background-size` attribute?

Comment: It squashes the image down to the width of the screen without `-webkit-background-size`. Removing the meta tag does nothing apart from make the page zoomable (which I don't want).